# How should I use requestAction in the view with CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.0

My code:

```
// View/Activities/index.ctp
...
<div>
    <?php echo $this->requestAction('/Activities/ajax_list/'.$categoryId,['return']);?>
</div>
...

//View/Activitest/ajax_list.ctp
....
<?php echo $this -> Html -> image("/img/add1.jpg"); ?>
...
<?php echo $this->Html->link('add_project', array('controller'=>'projects', 'action'=>'add', $categoryId)); ?>
....
```

I want to include the view 'ajax_list' into the 'index',and it has been displayed but the url of image and link was wrong.

Then I debug the Cake/Routing/RequestActionTrait.php , "requestAction" function I find "$request = new Request($params);" the $request->base , $request->webroot are null.

Could some one tell me how should I fix it?

Comment: "_the url of image and link was wrong_" means what exactly?

Comment: the "src" of <img> and the "href" of <a> all lose the "base" . E.g.  my project is "Pro" the correct <img> should be "<img src="/Pro/img/add.jpg" alt="">" but now I get "<img src="img/add.jpg" alt="">"

Comment: I suppose this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591852/how-to-use-requestaction-in-cakephp-3-0

Comment: The devs have solved this bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$base`/`$webroot` properties not being set in the new request might be considered a bug, or maybe the docs are just missing a proper example solution, I can't tell for sure, you might want to [**report this over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues) and see what the devs say.

### Use view cells instead of `requestAction()`!

Whenever applicable you're better off using view cells instead of requesting actions, as they avoid all the overhead that comes with dispatching a new request.

See **[Cookbook > Views > View Cells](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html)**

### No models involved? Use elements!

In case no models are involed, and all you are doing is generating HTML, then you could simply use elements.

See **[Cookbook > Views > Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements)**

### Fixing `requestAction()`

A possible workaround would be to use a dispatcher filter that fills the empty `$base`/`$webroot` properties with the necessary values, something like

**src/Routing/Filter/RequestFilterFix.php**

```php
namespace App\Routing\Filter;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Routing\DispatcherFilter;

class RequestFixFilter extends DispatcherFilter
{
    public function beforeDispatch(Event $event)
    {
        $request = $event->data['request'];
        /* @var $request \Cake\Network\Request */

        if ($request->param('requested')) {
            $request->base = '/pro';
            $request->webroot = '/pro/';
            $request->here = $request->base . $request->here;
        }
    }
}
```

**config/bootstrap.php**

```php
// ...

// Load the filter before any other filters.
// Must at least be loaded before the `Routing` filter.
DispatcherFactory::add('RequestFix');

DispatcherFactory::add('Asset');
DispatcherFactory::add('Routing');
DispatcherFactory::add('ControllerFactory');
// ...
```

See also **[Cookbook > Routing > Dispatcher Filters > Building a Filter](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html#building-a-filter)**

Comment: Thank you for your help,I have used the Dispatcher Fiters to solve the problem,I will report this problem to see what the devs say,thank you again.