# How to use requestAction in cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp-3.0

At 2.0, I use `requestAction` like this:

```
<?=$this->Form->input('list',array('options'=>$this->requestAction(……)?>
```

But At 3.0, I use `requestAction` nothing display. I don't know how to write options data source.

Answer (score 0):

In Cake 3, the results from requestAction must be returned through the response object rather than directly like they were in Cake 2. This is most easily accomplished with JSON encoding.

In the function that you are calling through requestAction:

```
$options = $table->find(...);
$this->response->body(json_encode($options));
return $this->response;
```

And then in the view your options parameter would be

```
'options'=>json_decode($this->requestAction(……), true)
```