# How to access a controller action , from ctp file in CakePHP 3

Tags: model-view-controller, action, cakephp-3.x, ctp

I want to access a controller action from ctp file. Here my action name and ctp file name is different. For example I created an action in the name of tickets ,and my view ctp file name is ticket_title. How to do this ?

This is my action : ticket

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
public function ticket()
{
 $ticket=$this->Tickets->find('all');
 $this->set(compact('ticket'));
}
}
```

My view ctp file : ticket_title.ctp

```
<?php
$this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'ticket'));

foreach($ticket as $ticket1)
{
    echo $ticket1->title."<br/>";
}
```

Can any one help me ?.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318793/how-should-i-use-requestaction-in-the-view-with-cakephp-3-x

Answer (score 2):

Finally , it works by using render() method. 
In my action:

```
public function ticket()
{
$this->loadModel('Tickets');
$ticket=$this->Tickets->find('all');
$this->set(compact('ticket'));
$this->render('ticket_title');
}
```

And this is my ticket_title.ctp

```
<?php
foreach($ticket as $ticket1)
{
    echo $ticket1->title."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this object in **any other controller** or in **ctp file** where needed

**(in case of controller)**

```
use App\Controller\ControllerName;

$ControllerNameObj = new ControllerName;

$ControllerNameObj->functionName();
```

**(in case of ctp file)**

```
$abcObj = new \App\Controller\HomeController; 

$fetchdetail = $abcObj->ControllerfunctionName($parameter1, $parameter2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its working in **CTP of Cake PHP 3** . You can use this object in any other controller or in ctp file where needed

**(in case of controller)**

```
use App\Controller\ControllerName;

$ControllerNameObj = new ControllerName;

$ControllerNameObj->functionName();
```

**(in case of ctp file)**

```
$abcObj = new \App\Controller\HomeController;

$fetchdetail = $abcObj->ControllerfunctionName($parameter1, $parameter2);
```